# Starting the Apache2 service(os 5) access is denied

Tags: apache

I installed apache msi from their website in my windows 7 machine.

I get the following error in the log file when try my domain & port name through IE,

```
Starting the Apache2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2: Failed to open the service.
Starting the Apache2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2: Failed to open the service.
Starting the Apache2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2: Failed to open the service.
Starting the Apache2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2: Failed to open the service.
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2 Service
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 14):

while opening the command prompt you have to open it as " run as administrator" then you can able to start/stop the apache server succesfully in windows

steps to start/stop apache server in windows:
 click on start menu --> enter cmd in search box --> right click on cmd --> Run as Administrator --> go to the bin folder of apache server --> start/stop the server

check the logs for status

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

Check if the Administrators security group has full access to the xampp folder or xampplite folder.

Comment: how do you do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Apache just needs permission to write on logs directory.
You can get this grant it to user running httpd.exe process

Answer (score 0):

If everything seems correct, just check the box "Use default" in Java tab at the top